Angular Paginator Displays "1-10 of 10" After Navigating after First Page despite correct Total Item Count
I'm facing an issue with Angular Material's MatPaginator where it displays "1-10 of 10" after navigating to the second page, despite the API returning the correct total item count. The pagination works fine on the first page, but as soon as I switch to the second page, the paginator fails to update correctly. I really dont understand why, the logs seems correct. I use angular 17 with standalone components.
    export class BattlesDashboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'title', 'views', 'platform', 'likes'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Battle>();
  totalItems = 0;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

  constructor(private battlesService: BattlesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

    this.loadBattles();

    this.paginator.page.subscribe(() => this.loadBattles());
  }

  loadBattles() {
    const pageIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex;
    const pageSize = this.paginator.pageSize;

    this.battlesService.getBattles(pageIndex + 1, pageSize).subscribe(result => {
      this.dataSource.data = result.data;
      this.totalItems = result.totalItems;
      this.paginator.length = this.totalItems;

      console.log(`Total Items: ${this.totalItems}`);
      console.log(`Loaded Battles: ${this.dataSource.data.length}`);
    }, error => {
      console.error("Error loading data:", error);
    });
  }
}

The paginator works fine on the first page.
The total item count is correctly logged as 717, and 10 items are displayed as expected.
However, after navigating to the second page, the paginator displays "1-10 of 10", even though the console logs show that totalItems is still correctly set to 717.
The Logs:
 ____ getBattles ____
battles.service.ts:26 Total Items Header: 717
battles.service.ts:27 Total Items Parsed: 717
battles-dashboard.component.ts:58 Total Items: 717
battles-dashboard.component.ts:59 Loaded Battles: 10
core.mjs:30066 Angular hydrated 28 component(s) and 410 node(s), 0 component(s) were skipped. Learn more at https://angular.dev/guide/hydration.
battles.service.ts:19  ____ getBattles ____
battles.service.ts:26 Total Items Header: 717
battles.service.ts:27 Total Items Parsed: 717
battles-dashboard.component.ts:58 Total Items: 717
battles-dashboard.component.ts:59 Loaded Battles: 10

The only way it works is with an extra setTimeout, but that doesn't seem like the right way to me.
setTimeout(() => {
        this.paginator.length = this.totalItems;
        this.paginator.pageIndex = pageIndex;
      });
    });

Is it possible that there are complications with Angular's hydration process? Or does anyone have other ideas? or is the setTimeoutw way the right one?
Thanks in advance!

You're "paginating" by API, so your paginator should be used as "standalone". That's remove the line
//remove this line
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

BTW: you should mannage also when sort the table. In this SO you have an example that include filter and loading, but if only want to filter you can do something like
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const sort = this.sort.sortChange.pipe(
      tap(() => this.paginator.firstPage())
    );
    merge(sort, this.paginator.page)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(res => {
          const pageIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex;
          const pageSize = this.paginator.pageSize;
          return this.battlesService.getBattles(pageIndex + 1,
                                                pageSize,
                                                this.sort.active,
                                                this.sort.direction)
        }))
      .subscribe((res: any[]) => {
           this.dataSource.data = result.data;
           this.totalItems = result.totalItems;
           this.paginator.length = this.totalItems;      });
  }

